# How to split the nav bar into 3 sections?

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm making a review website, and I followed a tutorial on a navbar. The navbar is responsive. However, I need to add and edit a few of its elements, but I cannot figure out how to. I want to split my nav bar into 3 elements, my logo on my left, my websites pages / items in the centre, and login and register on the right. I have included all my html and css below

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@700&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, #1b2735 0%, #090a0f 100%);
  color: white;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  --colour1: #fff;
  --colour2: #1b2735;
}

.nav-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, #1b2735 0%, #090a0f 100%);
  padding: 12px 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.logo img {
  width: 60px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 30px;
}

.menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu li a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.open-menu {
  position: absolute;
  columns: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: none;
}

.close-menu {
  position: absolute;
  columns: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  display: none;
}

#check {
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 610px) {
  .menu {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -100%;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: var(--colour2);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  }
  .menu li {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
  .menu li a {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .open-menu,
  .close-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  #check:checked~.menu {
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav-bar">
      <li class="logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="youreview_logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
      </li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="check">
      <span class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <label for="check" class="close-menu"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></label>
                </span>
      <label for="check" class="open-menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Your html is invalid `ul` can only have `li` as children and `li` can only be a child of `ul` or `ol` and not `span`

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is separate your logo, navbar links and login and register in different divs, and use the width element in your css to give them equal spacing. A bit like this:

html:

```
<!-- Navbar code -->
<div class="logo-spacing">
    <!-- your logo -->
</div>
<div class="pages-spacing">
    <!-- your page links -->
</div>
<div class="login-spacing">
    <!-- your login/register links -->
</div>
<!-- navbar closing code -->
```

css:

```
.logo-spacing {
    width: 33%
}

.pages-spacing {
    width: 33%
}

.login-spacing {
    width: 33%
}
```

Haven't tested it, but this hopefully helps.
A different approach would be to use bootstrap 5 grid, this link has more info on it: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/#grid-options